# Slow filesystem for specific route.name

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic

So suddenly without any deployments in 2 weeks, one route started to be super slow (6-30seconds instead of usual 0.4sec)

I've checked database, redis (cache & sessions on it), restarted them - nothing.

Thought to create a debug route and contoller's method, to check which part causes issues. Started with simple:

```
Route::get('/random-debug-url/{category}/{slug}', 'ContentController@index')->name('content.index');
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', 'ContentController@index')->name('content.index.old');
```

Gone to check the new url (random-debug-url/category/slug) - yeah, still loading slowly. Checked old url (category/slug) - boom, works as fast as always (~400ms). The only difference, that the old route have changed route-name. The new url, has old route name, and it still performs poorly.

Specs:
Laravel 8.12, PHP 7.4, Opcache

Newrelic report:
https://prnt.sc/26d8mni

It says that in worst case (61s) this took 99.999% of time:

```
Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::Illuminate\Filesystem\{closure}   7   60,700 ms   100%
```

Any ideas? How come the same controller/method perform differently just by having different route name?

Comment: have you tried `route:cache`, just to rebuild route cache?

Comment: Yep, route,view,config - all caches were cleared. And because I use opcache, I had to restart nginx  after updating files.

Comment: thats some goofy stuff; can you try to *only* define the single route that you're visiting while you test it? I would just start commenting out middleware and service providers.

Comment: Both of those routes are having 100% the same code (controllers,views, middlewares etc). The only difference they have - route name. With a new route name, the same url works flawlessly. This issue just occured once again. Will try to take another look